# Difference between 獣｛しし｝ and 野獣｛やじゅう｝ (beast)

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances

I learnt the words 獣{しし} and 野獣{やじゅう} and their definitions look too similar. Can someone explain me the difference between them?

While searching more for beast words, I also found that 獣 could also be spelt けもの or けだもの (also written in katakana　ケダモノ).

Comment: Everywhere I could find it,  獣{しし} is marked as [outdated](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/96083/m0u/%E7%8D%A3/) or [archaic](http://beta.jisho.org/word/5185a0e6d5dda729540375e6). Where did you come across 獣{しし}?

Comment: When I learnt 原始人, I searched for [an example on tangorin](http://tangorin.com/examples/%E5%8E%9F%E5%A7%8B%E4%BA%BA), then discovered 獣 and learnt it ^^. Will remove it from my list then, thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

獣 is always read **けもの** or **けだもの** in modern Japanese.

> [けもの](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%91%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE)

Simply refers to any kind of beast or animal.

> [けだもの](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%91%E3%81%A0%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE)

It's only used for emotionally deprived, unscrupulous, monstrous individuals, like a murderer, rapist or barbarian. It always refers to the actual perpetrator, so for example, you wouldn't call Adolf Hitler a けだもの. Think of [Chucky from Child's Play](https://www.google.com/search?q=chucky&espv=2&biw=1024&bih=568&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=3wBiVLyGB8HamAXp14LACA&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ&dpr=2#tbm=isch&q=child%27s+play+chucky).

> [野獣{やじゅう}](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%84%E3%81%98%E3%82%85%E3%81%86)

Also means beast or brute, but it doesn't carry any negative connotation like けだもの.

> しし is not used in modern Japanese as 獣, but 獅子{しし} is an outdated form of ライオン.

Comment: FWIW, it bears noting that the しし related to 獣 is distinct from the しし reading for 獅子. The latter is just the _on'yomi_ of the kanji spelling 獅子. Meanwhile, the しし reading for 獣 (and various other animal kanji, such as 鹿) is the _kun'yomi_, and this しし is ultimately cognate with the now-rare _kun'yomi_ for the kanji 肉 -- these various _kun'yomi_ words all had to do with meat, and the animals hunted for their meat. See also http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/肉#Japanese.

Comment: I thought maybe the OP could have confused 獣{しし} with 獅子{しし}, they are of course unrelated, and the former never used in modern Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

現代でもライオンを意味する「獅子（しし）」はたまに使われます。ライオンの写真をみて「獅子」という人はお年寄りを除いてあまりいないように思います。古来日本にはライオンがいませんので、何百年も昔の方は伝聞できっとライオンの姿や形などを聞いて、威厳のある獅子を屏風に描く・・・とかしていたのでしょう。日本の古語に疎い自分でも、中学の古文の授業で「しし」に触れましたが、そのときの意味はライオンではなく「肉」でした。「猪（いのしし）」という動物は日本人なら誰でも知っている筈なので、獣（けもの）を「しし」と当て字で読ませても違和感はありません。食べる肉は動物である「獣」から得られますし。そうやってリンクしているわけです。作者には作者が醸し出したい世界があるのでしょう。私は「獣」を「しし」と読まされれて感じることは、古風めいた表現だなということであり、出てくる動物のイメージは日本の伝統画に出てくる「獅子」のようなものです。だから、「しし」と聴いたら荒々しいイメージも持ちます。ネットで画像を見て、（現代の一般的な日本人が）昔の日本人が獅子に対するイメージをどのように持っていたと思っているかを、その一部を共有したいなら、「獅子舞」の獅子の頭の部分を見ると分かり易いかもしれないです。専門家でないから責任は持てませんが・・・。