# The correct reading for 血啜の獣斧 and 約束されざる守護の車輪チ

Tags: translation, readings

What is the correct reading for these two lines:

血啜の獣斧 - Chisusu no Shishi Ono or Chisusu no Kemono Ono?
約束されざる守護の車輪チ - Yakusokusarezaru Shugo no Sharin or Yakusoku Sarezaru Shugo no Sharin?

I know that 獣(しし) is no longer used for beast, and it's more used for dogs/lions and even for the left-hand guardian dog at a Shinto shrine.

Comment: I guess it depends on how the authors want to read it, but isn't ちすす a little strange?

Comment: @snailboat: Exactly. Even as it is a made up word, my guess for a reading would be ちすすり as that is the stem.

Comment: What's that チ after 車輪? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 2):

The words in the former are made up so don't think you can tell what the "correct" way to read it. You'll have better luck looking up the meaning of the kanji. As for the later, looks good to me either way.

*EDIT*:
血啜 means sucking-in blood (like you'd suck-in ramen noodles), although it's normally a sentence and not a noun (血を啜る). The noun here sounds made up. This description is normally reserved for super-natural, evil things (like 化け猫). 獣斧 would mean a "beast axe", possibly "axe used by a beast (as in super-natural, evil beast)". That's also a made up word. I don't quite know how to parse `約束されざる守護の車輪` but something like "Wheel of protection that wasn't promised"?

Comment: I'm looking! But, I'm also confused with: 獣(しし), beast (esp. one used for its meat, such as a boar or a deer), in other words, beasts we can eat; 獣(けもの), beasts, animals, monsters; [Other topic about this situation](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19458/difference-between-%E7%8D%A3-%E3%81%97%E3%81%97-and-%E9%87%8E%E7%8D%A3-%E3%82%84%E3%81%98%E3%82%85%E3%81%86-beast). Even Yahoo says 獣(しし) is a reference to beast meat.

Comment: @Mr.G: Added some stuff, HTH

Comment: Yes, you're correct about everything! OMG, thank you! By the way, after reading your statement, I should read 獣 as けもの rather than しし?

Comment: @Mr.G: Yeah probably not しし. If I had to guess I'd read it じゅうふ

Comment: My intuition was 「けつてつのじゅうふ」, too. It's possible to read it as something like 「ちずすりのけものおの」 using kun-yomi readings. But since this is from a non-Japanese character, I'd say けつてつのじゅうふ is more likely. しし is very unlikely.

Comment: @naruto I'm impressed you know the on-yomi for 啜! :-)  Would けってつ be more likely than けつてつ, do you think?  EDIT: I think that the Noun-Verb order is unusual for a 漢語, actually.

Comment: It's just because I happen to know a word 吸啜反射【きゅうてつはんしゃ】 :-) けってつ is possible, but I'm not sure which is more likely.